# como posso atribuir um valor de um campo em outro em javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

tenho um código em javascript que pega o valor do campo quantidade com onkeypress porém eu precisaria também pegar o valor do campo id ou seja o esse valor serjá enviado via ajax para outra pagina para esta fazendo um update só que não estou conseguindo mandar também manda o valor do campo id alguém tem uma sugestão, eu gostaria de esta mandando o valor do campo id e do campo qtd para o parametro da função pelo onkeypress do campo qtd.

segue o código em ajax:

```
<script>
function update(str) {  
  //var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("result").inner =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "update.php?qtd="+str+"&unidade="+str+"&desc="+str+"&custo="+str, true);
  alert(str);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

segue o código em php:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Quatidade</th>
            <th>Unidade</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Custo</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
        while($result = @mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<tr class='odd gradeX' id='result'>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' disabled='disabled' id='codigo' name='codigo' value='".$result[0]."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='qtd' name='qtd' value='".$result[1]."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='unidade' name='unidade' value='".$result[2]."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='desc' name='desc' value='".$result[3]."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='custo' name='custo' value='".$result[4]."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text'  disabled='disabled' value='".$result[5]."'/></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";        
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Qual campo Id você quer capiturar e mandar? Esse Id da linha no TR cujo nome está como Result?

Comment: sim, são valores que estão pegando do banco, esses valores pode ser alterado pelo o usuário, quando o usuário da o enter ele manda o valor do campo clicado gostaria de saber se tem como mandar junto com esse valor o valor do campo id junto

Comment: leo era mais ou menos isso que queria porém ele ainda pega a primeira linha precisava que pegasse a linha do campo alterado, no seu exemplo ele trás os valores do  campo em array porém somente o que mexi tras certo o os outros são valores da primeira linha.

Answer (score 1):

> O atributo onkeypress ocorre quando o usuário pressiona uma tecla (no teclado), e o valor no campo é inserido quando a tecla é liberada, portanto o evento é disparado antes da entrada dos dados no campo.
>
> Se for alterar apenas um campo pode-se usar o atributo onBlur. O atributo onblur dispara no momento em que o elemento perde o foco.

```js
function update(str) {  
  var qtd = document.getElementById('qtd').value;  
  var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
  var unidade = document.getElementById('unidade').value;
  var desc = document.getElementById('desc').value;
  var custo = document.getElementById('custo').value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("result").inner =
    this.responseText;
   }
};
  //xhttp.open("GET", "update.php?qtd="+qtd+"&unidade="+unidade+"&desc="+desc+"&custo="+custo, true);
  //alert(str);
  alert("update.php?qtd="+qtd+"&unidade="+unidade+"&desc="+desc+"&custo="+custo);
  //xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Quatidade</th>
        <th>Unidade</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Custo</th>
        <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr class='odd gradeX' id='result'>
  <td><input type='text' size="8" disabled='disabled' id='codigo' name='codigo' value='ABCD'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' size="8" onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='qtd' name='qtd' value='200'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' size="8" onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='unidade' name='unidade' value='metros'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' size="10" onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='desc' name='desc' value='pano p/ manga'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' size="8" onkeypress='update(this.value)' id='custo' name='custo' value='20.00'/></td>
  <td><input type='text' size="8" disabled='disabled' value='02/04/2017'/></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>        
</table>
```

> **A melhor forma é através de um botão com o evento onClick.**

**Script**

```
function loadDoc() {

  var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
  var qtd = document.getElementById('qtd').value;  
  var codigo = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
  var unidade = document.getElementById('unidade').value;
  var desc = document.getElementById('desc').value;
  var custo = document.getElementById('custo').value;
  var data = document.getElementById('data').value;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
         this.responseText;
        }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "update.php?codigo="+codigo+"&qtd="+qtd+"&unidade="+unidade+"&desc="+desc+"&custo="+custo+"&data="+data, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Quatidade</th>
    <th>Unidade</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
    <th>Custo</th>
    <th>Data</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

  <?php 
    while($result = @mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr class='odd gradeX' id='result'>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='codigo' name='codigo' value='".$result[0]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='qtd' name='qtd' value='".$result[1]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='unidade' name='unidade' value='".$result[2]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='desc' name='desc' value='".$result[3]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='custo' name='custo' value='".$result[4]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' id='cdata' name='data' value='".$result[5]."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><button type='button' onclick='loadDoc()'>Submit</button></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";        
    }
  ?>       
</table>
```